# ubuntu not working

Tags: dual-boot, mac, refit

I have a macbook pro (15 inch, mid 2009) with OSX Yosemite 10.10.3. At first I wanted a dual boot... I have tried: -live disc boot with ubutnu 14.10 -Newly burned 14.10 & 15.04 as well -ubuntu 12.04 (both AMD 64 & intel x86 None of these would boot, so then I installed rEFIt. rEFIt sees the disc only 1/3 of the time and when it does it goes to the white page with the four diamond icon and spits out all of the earlier mentioned discs. I have tried partitioning disc first and then with rEFIt partition tool and nothing is working. At first I was wanting to dual boot but now I am so frustrated I just want my ubuntu back but on my mac machine...please help me get this done...I have asked before and tried the advice, looked at ALOT of other Q&A and nothing is seeming to work. What is wrong. I would love a step by step for an apparent noob like me.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "rEFIt sees the disc only 1/3 of the time and when it does it goes to the white page with the four diamond icon and spits out all of the earlier mentioned discs." rEFIt's boot menu displays EFI-mode and BIOS-mode *boot loaders,* not disks. Also, it's critical to understand what happens in the 2/3 of the time when rEFIt doesn't "see the disc" -- does the system crash? Does rEFIt display a menu that's missing options? Do you see an error message? Does it boot straight to Windows?

Comment: the other 2/3 of the time rEFIt shows only my mac hd and restore and no other option to boot from...then after restarting 2 or 3 times the live ubuntu disc shows up as an option but says it is windows then when I choose to boot from that it shows a white screen with the rEFIt diamonds logo in the center and after a few seconds it spits out the disc and stops until I restart it

Comment: I suspect this may be a scanning problem; sometimes disks don't appear immediately when an EFI application (like rEFIt) starts up. In rEFIt, there's not much you can do about this, but if you use rEFInd instead of rEFIt, you can hit the Esc key to cause a re-scan of your disks. If this works and you need it all the time, you can use the `scandelay` option in `refind.conf`.

Comment: I just finished installing a triple boot of Yosemite, Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04.2 on my mid 2007 iMac. I also used rEFInd to boot Ubuntu. If interested I could outline the steps I used.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using rEFInd instead of rEFIt?

http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html